# How to use Easy breadcrumb module so that breadcrumb reflects the URL path segments?

Tags: breadcrumbs

For example, if URL ends with /test/flower , breadcrumb should be Home/test/flower.

First time working with this module,and it's not clear to me how to do this.
Could you please help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Easy Breadcrumb works on the principle that every segment in your path is actually a reachable page (more on this later) and it builds the page's breadcrumb based on that path sequence. This works best when used with Pathauto to define aliases.

For example, let's take an example URL of `https://example.com/blogs/space/how-to-reach-mars`. The expectation is that the breadcrumb would be `Home / Blogs / Space / How To Reach Mars`. To make this work:

- `https://example.com/` must be a working page (it should, it's your home page)
- `https://example.com/blogs` could be a Views page listing all Article nodes.
- `https://example.com/blogs/space` could be a Views page with a contextual filter, filtering all Article nodes by a topic field containing "space".
- `https://example.com/blogs/space/how-to-reach-mars` an Article node whose alias is constructed with pattern `/blogs/[node:field_topic]/[node:title]`

Now Easy Breadcrumb does allow you to set unreachable pages on the in-between segments (e.g. the pages might be permissioned away or just non-existent), there is a configuration for this. In the example above, you can totally leave out the Views pages (`/blogs` and `/blogs/[topic]`) and still have the Node's path be `/blogs/space/how-to-reach-mars`. The breadcrumb on the page is still `Home / Blogs / Space / How To Reach Mars` but "Blog" and "Space" are unclickable.